# Running psexec from jenkins not showing logs

Tags: windows, jenkins, cmd

I have Jenkins with 'Execute Windows Batch Command' that runs PsExec on a second computer configured with `Execute Windows Batch Command`
and set to `cmd /c "FooPsExec.bat"`

When I run the Jenkins I do not see the execution of PsExec logs and all I see is:

```
"c:\pstools\PsExec.exe" XXXXXXXXX

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
```

And that's it, I can see that the process is running on the remote computer however I want to see the logs on Jenkins

If I open cmd on the Jenkins and run the `FooPsExec.bat` (not via Jenkins) it is working and logs are shown appropriately

How can I make the logs to be visiable

Answer (score 2):

You can use PaExec http://www.poweradmin.com/paexec/, which is an advanced version of PsExec